# Pre populate client database with PhoneGap (primary target Android)

Tags: database, cordova

There have been a few articles and questions about how to do this but they all seem to have a bias to iOS.

So first of all I am currently using PhoneGaps database functionality:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

I have a database I need for the app to run from as it contains a lot of information, probably about 1mb worth (can be exposed as .db/.sql). So I want to be able to make my PhoneGap app and build it for as many platforms as possible. However I want it so that as soon as the user has installed the app it automatically installs the database for them.

Some of the solutions seem to recommend creating the database on first boot, but this just seems a bit hack-ish and sidestepping the problem.

I am more than happy to switch over to use webSQL if Android, iOS and other providers support it, however as PhoneGap wraps any available native OS DB functionality it seemed more realistic that you can get an app to pre-populate an Android database and access it via PhoneGap than pre-populate a web database and access it via webSql.

Hopefully this question makes sense and there have been advances since mid last year, which seems to be the last up to date post on this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just answered another similar question on this topic. First PhoneGap doesn't implement the Storage function that is documented. In fact we take advantage of the sqlite and localStorage functionality that is implemented in all webkit based browsers.

My recommendation is for you to pre-populate a SQLite DB and on application startup copy the DB to the correct location so your app can access it. There is a good blog post on this topic at:

http://gauravstomar.blogspot.com/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+%28Gaurav+S+Tomar+%3A+Bootstrapping+Intelligence%29