# PouchDB preload database

Tags: cordova, pouchdb

Sorry is this is a silly question, then I am drowning in a glass of water (not rare BTW). Is there any way to setup a web (ideally cordova) application with a preloaded (ready to use) PouchDB database(s)? Ideally what I'd want is having a PouchDB database(s) file(s) ready to use when doing `db = new PouchDB('databaseName')` without having to load all documents at the very first time the app is run.

I know there is the `pouchdb-replication-stream` but I'd need the dump file to load and then the size of the application data would be duplicated (both in the dump file and then the PouchDB database(s)). Also no chance for remote loading.

Cheers!!

Comment: This might get you going in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004428/pre-populate-client-database-with-phonegap-primary-target-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Edit:** you can now preload a SQLite database or use pouchdb-load; there are instructions in [this blog post](https://pouchdb.com/2016/04/28/prebuilt-databases-with-pouchdb.html).*

Currently the only way to *completely* preload is to use the SQLite Plugin, then have a build step where you use PhantomJS and copy the SQLite files into your app.

I don't generally recommend the SQLite Plugin due to 1) general instability of implementation and 2) slowness compared to IndexedDB/WebSQL. So if I were writing such an app and I wanted the best possible preload performance, I would:

1. Use `pouchdb-dump-cli` to dump to a file
2. Load using `pouchdb-load` into a PouchDB, throw up a spinner on initial load while the app is loading if you really need to.

Some optimizations you could do here:

1. The `worker-pouch` plugin works on Android (not iOS sadly), and can be used to avoid blocking DOM operations. Should work with the `pouchdb-load` plugin, or you can just do everything inside of a worker (better to avoid *any* blocking, not just IndexedDB-related blocking).
2. To avoid blocking the user during initial load, break up your dump file into some subset of critical data, load that first and then load the rest of the data afterwards.

Comment: Thanks!! For now I'm gonna use the SQLite solution, despite has many unstable issues, but my db won't have large data requirements but the data pre-populated is a huge plus. I though about the dumping-loading solution as well (keep out so far as a backup in the case things go wrong). BTW, don't get exactly the role of phantomjs; and, my bad, I could resort to https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4063 before, or you could point me to :-)

Comment: PhantomJS would be to create the SQLite DBs from the command-line; else you'd have to spin up an Android emulator or something, run it, and then copy the SQLite DBs off the device manually. Which works too, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for clarification about phantomjs. In the end, I did it as you posted in the github issue I referenced above (using chrome). Now, when I try to load the sqlite db in a cordova test app with `createFromLocation: 1` and I do db.info(), I get `{"doc_count":0,"update_seq":0,"sqlite_plugin":true,"websql_encoding":"UTF-8","db_name":"guide300.sqlite","auto_compaction":false,"adapter":"websql"}`, but I know the sqlite db file has documents as I could see using straight sqlite API. Any hint on this? May Chrome to have to do something? Cheers!!